Simplifying an ODE in Bessel notation
I have the following Mathematica code:
 eq[r_] = 3  (1 + 2  a)  g1  r  y[r] - 2  (2   y'[r] + r  y''[r]);

DSolveValue[eq[r] == 0, y[r], r]

This gives me the output:
(*(E^(-Sqrt[(3/2)] Sqrt[g1 + 2 a g1] r) C[1])/r + (
 E^(Sqrt[3/2] Sqrt[(1 + 2 a) g1] r) C[2])/(
 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[(1 + 2 a) g1] r)*)

How do I convert it into Bessel Notation $r^n[J_n(kr)+Y_n(kr)]$?
Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!
Edit
Interestingly a more general solution as given here (equation 3.6) on page 7:
eq[r_] = (d - 1) y[r] - 2/f1 (y''[r] + (d - 2) y'[r]/r) == 0;

DSolveValue[eq[r], y[r], r]

Gives the answer as:
r^((3 - d)/2)
    BesselJ[1/2 (-3 + d), -((I Sqrt[(-1 + d) f1] r)/Sqrt[2])]  C[1] + 
 r^((3 - d)/2)
    BesselY[1/2 (-3 + d), -((I Sqrt[(-1 + d) f1] r)/Sqrt[2])]  C[2]

What makes Mathematica choose one form in the general and another in a more specialized setting?

Are you saying the output is equivalent to your "Bessel Notation" provided we solve for the right parameters $n$ and $k$? I have my doubts, since the one side is linear in two parameters and the desired form is not linear in either parameter. Perhaps only those who know what it means to convert to "Bessel Notation" can answer this, but if you can explain what it means in a way that makes the problem seem to have an answer, I might have a good chance of finding the answer. Maybe. Tx.

Also you need to copy second and higher derivatives in input form. I don't know why WRI doesn't fix the copy/paste issue, but pasting your eq[r] into a notebook yields an invalid differential equation.

Actually I was trying to use the notation given in this paper in equation (3.7) on page 7

My guess for the last question is that sometimes a diff. eq. can be solved in more than one way. It seems to me that multiple methods are more likely to apply to a specific DE than to a general DE. I also think DSolve[] probably returns the solution from the first method to succeed.

For instance, Frobenius's theory says $y(r) = r^k u(r)$, where $k$ is a solution to the indicial equation (that is $k=-1$ or $k=0$) and $u$ is analytic. Such a substitution yields a linear equation with constant coefficients, which makes a pretty simple method of solution. yeq = 3 (1 + 2 a) g1 r y[r] - 2 (2 y'[r] + r y''[r]); ueq = yeq /. y -> Function[r, u[r]/r] // Simplify; {y[r] -> u[r]/r} /. DSolve[ueq == 0, u[r], r] doesn't quite give the same solution (different constant coefficients).

@MichaelE2, you are right. Thanks for the explanation.

I could not yet figure a way to FunctionExpand your result to Bessel type functions. May be there is a way. But here is my hand solution showing the solution as Bessel functions. So in theory, there should be a way to convert Mathematica's result to Bessel functions (assuming DSolve result is correct :)
At the end I also verified this solution using Mathematica, and Mathematica agrees it is correct.
Hand solution
The general form of Bessel ode
$$
r^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+ry^{\prime}+\left(  r^{2}-n^{2}\right)  y=0
$$
The generalized form of Bessel ode  is (by Bowman 1958)
\begin{equation}
r^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+\left(  1-2\alpha\right)  ry^{\prime}+\left(  \beta
^{2}\gamma^{2}r^{2\gamma}-\left(  n^{2}\gamma^{2}-\alpha^{2}\right)  \right)
y=0\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Your ode is
$$
-2ry^{\prime\prime}-4y^{\prime}+\left(  3\left(  1+2a\right)  gr\right)  y=0
$$
Or, by multiplying throughout by $r$
\begin{align}
-2r^{2}y^{\prime\prime}-4ry^{\prime}+\left(  3gr^{2}+6agr^{2}\right)  y  &
=0\nonumber\\
-r^{2}y^{\prime\prime}-2ry^{\prime}+\left(  \left(  \frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)
r^{2}\right)  y  & =0\nonumber\\
r^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+2ry^{\prime}+\left(  -\left(  \frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)
r^{2}\right)  y  & =0\tag{2}
\end{align}
Comparing (1) and (2) gives
\begin{align*}
\left(  1-2\alpha\right)    & =2\\
\left(  \beta^{2}\gamma^{2}r^{2\gamma}-\left(  n^{2}\gamma^{2}-\alpha
^{2}\right)  \right)    & =\left(  -\frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  r^{2}
\end{align*}
Hence $-2\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$. The second equation above becomes
$$
\left(  \beta^{2}\gamma^{2}r^{2\gamma}-\left(  n^{2}\gamma^{2}-\frac{1}
{4}\right)  \right)  =-\left(  \frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  r^{2}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\beta^{2}\gamma^{2}r^{2\gamma}  & =-\left(  \frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)
r^{2}\tag{3}\\
\left(  n^{2}\gamma^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)    & =0\tag{4}
\end{align}
Eq (3) gives $2\gamma=2$ or $\gamma=1$. Hence the above becomes
\begin{align}
\beta^{2}  & =-\left(  \frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  \tag{5}\\
\left(  n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)    & =0\tag{6}
\end{align}
Eq (6) gives $n^{2}=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and Eq. (5) gives $\beta=i\sqrt{\left(
\frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  }$
But the general solution of the Bessel ODE given in (1) is known and given by
(for non-integer $n$) as
$$
y=r^{\alpha}\left(  c_{1}J_{n}\left(  \beta r^{\gamma}\right)  +c_{2}
J_{-n}\left(  \beta r^{\gamma}\right)  \right)
$$
Substituting values found above for $n,\beta,\gamma,\alpha$ the above becomes
(using the positive root for $n$)
$$
y=r^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(  c_{1}J_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(  i\sqrt{\left(  \frac
{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  }r\right)  +c_{2}J_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(  i\sqrt{\left(
\frac{3}{2}g+3ag\right)  }r\right)  \right)
$$
This could be rewritten using $Y_{k}$ modified Bessel function. see relations between them somewhere else. (see this page for example )
Verification using Mathematica
ode = 3 (1 + 2 a) g r y[r] - 2 (2 y'[r] + r y''[r])
e = Sqrt[3/2*g + 3*a*g];
mysol = y -> 
  Function[{r}, 
   1/Sqrt[r]*( C[1]*BesselJ[1/2, I*e*r] + C[2]*BesselJ[-1/2, I*e*r])]
ode /. mysol // FullSimplify

gives
(* 0 *)
Update
I noticed that Mathematica likes to rewrite Bessels automatically in terms of hyperbolic trig functions. May be this is why FunctionExpand did not show Bessel functions as output
mysol = ( C[1] BesselJ[1/2, I e r] + C[2] BesselJ[-(1/2), I e r])/Sqrt[r]



BTW, FunctionExpand[] is meant to go the other way, from special to elementary functions, according to the docs.

@MichaelE2 I see. This is why it did not work then :)  Either way, I could not find a way to show that Mathematica's DSolve result is same as the solution using Bessel functions.

Thank you for the detailed analysis Nasser. Actually I was working with this paper equation (3.7) on page 7 where they say that an ode with some given form can be written in Bessel Notation.

@codebpr, Yes, it is Bessel ODE, but need to first multiply it by $r$ to see that. May be computers do not do that and solve it using others ways, like using Lie symmetry method and may be other methods.  That explains why the answer given by Mathematica did not have explicit Bessel functions in it.

Ah I understand now, thanks for the answer again. It was quite helpful.

@MichaelE2 please see the edited question.

This comes close to Nasser's: Activate@DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][3 (1 + 2 a) g1 r y[r] - 2 (2 y'[r] + r y''[r]) == 0, y[r], r], u, t, r == Exp[t]] /. {u[t] -> y[r], t -> Log[r]} // Simplify[#, r > 0 && g1 + 2 a g1 > 0] &
